# Move c:\Users\<username>\.android directory to different location

Tags: android

I would like to move the c:\Users\.android directory to a different location. Is this configurable in the Eclipse/ADT environment on Windows?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

yes it is configurable

all you need to do is set the environmental variable "PATH" accordingly.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You may however change the default location for the .android directory by setting the environment variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME

Comment: Sorry but this didn't work neither. I copied the complete folder to a different location, added the environment var and changed the SDK location in Eclipse. This gave a "parseSdkContent failed java.lang.NullPointerException".

Comment: Harald I have a copy of sdk folder with me and whenever i need to install the android eclipse to any of machine i simply download the adt plugin and  copy paste the sdk folder from my backup only thing is you need to track the path of adb file cos it shifts from tools folder to platform tools when update sdk. n thanks for this -ve mark